# Django: can i give an argument to a form to use it for different cases?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i'm new to Django and i use one form twice for user accounts (username, password). The first user is required, the second one is alternatively.

The problem is, that the checkbox is displayed by the required, too. Can i give an argument to the view to avoid the checkbox by the first user and display it for a second user? I wanna do a case like

Is that possible? I dont wanna write two different classes with the same fields just because one different field.

My code:

views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    admin_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(request.POST or None, given_argument='admin')
    user_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(request.POST or None, given_argument='extra_user')

    if admin_form.is_valid():
            #do something
    if user_form.is_valid():
            #do something


else:
    admin_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user()
    user_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user()

return TemplateResponse(request, "services/database/add_service_database.html", {'admin_form': admin_form,
                                                                                 'user_form': user_form},)
```

forms.py

```
class MysqlDatabaseForm_user(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MysqlUser

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    given_argument = kwargs.pop('given_argument', None)
    super(MysqlDatabaseForm_user, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if given_argument == 'extra_user':
        self.fields['extra_user'] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    else:
        self.fields[given_argument] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

The else-case is for screening, what is in "given_argument". it seems to be empty

Comment: No, I didn't referring to you. The problem is on me, I can't understand and I'm having a headache. I want to help but my mind is not functioning that's why I said blaablaah just to relax and think straight. sorry...

Comment: ok, then Wishing you well! :)

Comment: I get low reputation and I answer 1 question only this day. This is a bad day huh... I will try to answer your question hmmmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MysqlDatabaseForm_user(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MysqlUser

    def __init__(self, given_argument, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MysqlDatabaseForm_user, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if given_argument == 'extra_user':
            self.fields['extra_user'] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)



def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        admin_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(request.POST, given_argument='admin') 
        user_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(request.POST, given_argument='extra_user')
        ...........
    else:
        admin_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(given_argument='admin') 
        user_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(given_argument='extra_user')

    return render(request, 'page.html', {
        'admin_form': admin_form,
        'user_form': user_form,
    })
```

Comment: Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  __init__() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

Comment: How did you implement it? the system takes only one value when you execute the function

Comment: views.py 'admin_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(request.POST or None, given_argument='admin')
        user_form = MysqlDatabaseForm_user(request.POST or None, given_argument='extra_user')'

Comment: i changed the classnames, don't matter about that

Comment: There's no reason to add `given_argument` as a separate argument to the constructor. That's what `*args` adn `**kwargs` are for.

Comment: @Brandon I don't know how to use *args and **kwargs that's why I create separate argument

Comment: @Bubbleboy Ok I get it now why is not working on you and you get the error because you put the function in the wrong way

Comment: @Bubbleboy please post your views.py code in your question, and I will update it

Comment: Welcome, I answer now your question correctly but a while ago I don't understand it. Thanks also to @Brandon I came up with the idea :)

Comment: by sending the form i got an error and tried @Brandon solution. it's more code, but i got no problems. the problem was "got multiple values for keyword argument 'given_argument'". now it works fine. finally. thanks again for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#forms.py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        given_argument = kwargs.pop('given_argument', None)
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if given_argument:
            if given_argument == 'extra_user':
                key = 'extra_user'
            else:
                key = given_argument.lower()
            self.fields[key] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

#views.py
def your_view(request):
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None, given_argument='extra_user',
        prefix='user')
    admin_form = UserForm(request.POST, given_argument='admin', prefix='admin')
    ...

#template.html
<form action="." method="post" enctype="[the enctype you need]">
    <ol>
        <li>User Form</li>
        {{ user_form.as_ul }}
    </ol>

    <ol>
        <li>Admin Form</li>
        {{ admin_form.as_ul }}
    </ol>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Just do an override of `__init__`, and pop the extra argument out of the `**kwargs` before calling `super()` on the class. This will allow you to pass in the argument, remove it from the `**kwargs` that the form class normally expects, and then pass on the remaining `**kwargs`.

You need to be careful about the value you pass in, if you're going to be assigning the key of the field from the argument you pass in. No special characters, spaces, etc.

You don't need to have a separate condition to instantiate the forms if it's a GET request - that's what `request.POST or None` accomplishes when it's passed to the form class constructor.

You also don't need two separate model form classes. You're passing in the key argument to the field constructor, so you can use the same form class, and just pass in your optional argument. You'll notice I've added the `prefix` argument to the forms to prevent naming collisions between the fields.

Comment: sounds good, but it doesn't work. have done it like you said.

Comment: i get no checkbox. neither by the form with argument nor without argument (where it shouldn't come)

Comment: Please send me a link to a Pastie for your view.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. but catherines code was a few seconds earlier online and works fine :)

Comment: That's fine, if you don't mind writing a bunch of code you don't need.

Comment: last comment on @catherine it the latest snapshot :)

Answer (score 0):

Have your code role its own form, by using modelform_factory. (With such a simple example, you could hand code this too. See Catherine's example below for a good example of hand coding.)

How about:

```
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
form_fields = ['extra_user'] if given_argument == 'extra_user' else []
user_form = modelform_factory(Model, form=MysqlDatabaseForm_user, fields=form_fields)
```

`user_form.is_valid()` should work because the `extra_user` field is `required=False`

Django lets you derive custom forms from a Model and its ModelForm counterpart. You can even create forms which don't validate immediately, but which you can use to create Model objects that save after some further activity. Specifically, you could...

```
if request.Post:
  form = user_form(request.POST)
  model_object = form.save(commit=False) # now you have an model instance, and no longer need the form
  model_object = process_object(model_object)
  model_object.save()
```

These two tools, the `modelform_factory`, and the ability to `form.save(commit=False)` usually will allow you to avoid redefining standard methods such as `__init__` and `save`. I usually find when I think I need to modify those methods, I am missing some functionality naturally built into Django.